# What is the source of the Birkat Habayit?

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, home-house

What is the source of the text of the Birkat Habayit:

[image: A hamsa with the following English text of Birkat Habayit, underneath the Hebrew word "Chay" inside a Jewish star, and the words "Birkat Habayit" in Hebrew]

> May this house be a place of happiness and health, of contentment,
>   generosity and hope, a home of creativity and kindness.
>   May those
>   who visit and those who live here know only blessing and peace.

I've seen them written on a hand, and some come with garlic, multi-colored beads, and some other strange objects.

Inspired by: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4423114#4423114

Comment: I hope it's not derived from the practice of Christians in central Europe who write an [acronym for *mansionem benedicat*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_%28holiday%29#Liturgical_practice_in_Western_churches) over their front door on January 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is anonymous in a modern hebrew,  here is a [document in pdf](http://www.ou.org/publications/ja/5760summer/legal-ea.pdf) of Rabbi Ari Zivotofsky:

> Over the last few decades, the so-called Birchat Habayit has found its way into many Jewish homes. Its words even have been used as a popular song on a recent Jewish album. This “prayer” seems to be a relatively recent phenomenon. The language  and style are modern Hebrew, indicating a recent composition.  Rabbi Shlomo Aviner,8 the rav of Beit El, has pointed out that the style is not a Jewish style. There is no “Yehi  ratzon” or “Ribon Olamim.” God is not addressed and no request is made.
>
> It is simply a statement. Rabbi Aviner is sure it is a translation from a non-Jewish source, and recalls a claim that the contents may be from a work by [Rudyard Kipling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudyard_Kipling). I have been unable to locate any such formulation in the writings of Kipling. Other scholars speculate that it is modern Hebrew poetry.

Comment: Maybe they are referring to the final stanza of Kipling's "[A Carol](http://www.bartleby.com/364/281.html)"? "God bless the master of this house, and all who sleep therein! And guard the fens from pirate folk, and keep us all from sin..."