# Text for birchat habayit

Tags: minhag, blessing, sources-mekorot

I'd like to write a couple birchos habayis and get them illuminated as gifts. Does anyone know of a good existing text? I'm looking for something five or six lines long, preferably not the usual one beginning בזה השער לא יבא צער.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16039/732

Comment: Based on the answer there, there is no "official" text and you can make up whatever you want

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Sounds like a good answer to me (or possibly a dupe).

Comment: I know there is no official text. I was hoping for ideas or suggestions for "unofficial" texts that I didn't know about. I'm sure there are quite a few.

Comment: Not Constructive?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's quite possible that short of an "official" text, there's something out there that was composed by someone with insight, talent, and possibly even authority. I'd say it's constructive to seek such.

Comment: @IsaacMoses So answers citing famous authors are ok answers, but if I write my own it's a bad answer? That's ok by me (and I think the only way this question can remain constructive), but it needs to be clarified explicitly in the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think that's right. We're not optimized for generating new creative work.

Comment: @IsaacMoses [BeChavod!](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/17538/edit)