# Birkas habayis - source

Tags: tefilla, home-house

I have noticed that many families have a tefillah entitled 'birkas habayis' at the entrance to their home. There seems to be multiple, similar נוסחאות for this tefilla.

Example:

בזה השער לא יבוא צער.
בזאת הדירה לא תבוא צרה.
בזאת הדלת לא תבוא בהלה.
בזאת המחלקה לא תבוא מחלוקת.
בזה המקום תהי ברכה ושלום

Why do the נוסחאות vary?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16039 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17538

Comment: Could you provide the text to one? Given that you have given no basis for any such formal institution, I am not sure what is strange with different people composing different prayers for their homes.